# String format to a String number c#

Tags: c#, string

how can i use like a mask or format for a string for example if i write in the console 6789 this print 67.89 or 13467 the out give me 134.67, and that goes for 0 to , output = 0.00, I've been trying with `N2` format but only works with the 0 or with the `{0:f2}` , in other words a format that put the decimal place at the last two places of the given string number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but it works just fine.

```
int number;
string text = "0123456";

Int32.TryParse(text, out number);

Console.WriteLine("{0:N2}",(double)number/100);
```